# In Scala, how to convert FilterMonadic to a List?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I got the `FilterMonadic` from the following line:

```
val f = ((2 to 10) withFilter (_ > 5) withFilter( _ < 8))
```

However, I found `f` doesn't have a `toList` method. Does anyone have ideas about how to convert it into a List?

And what are the main different between `withFilter` and `filter` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably `f.map(identity)`, which doesn't necessarily return a `List`, but an appropriate type of sequence, based on the original sequence type before filtering.

If you want strictly a `List`, convert the result to `List` afterwards: `f.map(identity).toList`.

As for the difference, for most collections `filter` immediately performs the filtering, builds a new collection in memory and returns it, and `withFilter` returns an object, which stores the original collection and does the filtering only when an element is requested.

Comment: Only that it returns a `Vector` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
scala> val f = ((2 to 10) withFilter (_ > 5) withFilter( _ < 8))
f: scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic[Int,scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter@60b8da0

scala> f.flatMap(List(_)).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(6, 7)
```

Comment: Yes, it is monadic hack! `List` is a monad, so is `identity`.